# PHP File cache not work in loops

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I work with [Simple PHP File Cache](https://github.com/cosenary/Simple-PHP-Cache) Class. I add data set(add `MySQL` result) into `PHP loops` using `foreach` method Like This :

PHP CODE:

```
   $c = new Cache();
    foreach($_POST['audio'] as $audio){
    SQL::put("INSERT INTO " . NEWS_FILES . " (news_id, url, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", $id, $audio,"audio");
    $c->store($id, array(
    'action' => array(
    $id, $video,"audio")
    ));
    }
```

result in cache file:

```
{"202":{"time":1410452801,"expire":0,"data":{"action":[202,"http:\/\/localhost\/user\/uploads\/files\/1\/thumbs\/1\/audio\/download-kid-photo-c.jpg","audio"]}}}
```

Now, I have 4 files for id 202 But cache class insert only one files in file. Cache Class not work with loops!! how to fix this?

Class File [HERE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosenary/Simple-PHP-Cache/master/cache.class.php)

Comment: You're just overwriting the cache each time. You have to use a unique name.

Comment: You right But i need to add more file with one id like Lukasz first example. i.e: i have 5 image for One id and need to cache image data to cache file. how to !!

Comment: Stuff them into an array and then store the array. IF you want to update it then retrieve, append to array, store.

Comment: can u share your idea code here?

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by overriding identifiers in cache. 
This is sth like nosql key value storage. Key should be unique identifier.
You've got:

```
202 => file1,
202 => file2,
202 => file3,
202 => file4
```

And it's impossible to get each file by identifier.
It should looks like:

```
201 => file1,
202 => file2,
203 => file3,
204 => file4
```

Comment: You right But i need to add more file with one id like your first example. i.e: i have 5 image for One id and need to cache image data to cache file. how to !!

Comment: Move $c->store() after foreach loop and only collect your files in foreach. Then push that array with files with the id 202